# Batch Mode and Custom Error Handling in Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

Before I started to use Spring Cloud Stream, I was using Spring-Kafka and its support for batch consumption and custom error handling. Notice the last two lines of this snippet:

```
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, byte[]> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConcurrency(this.consumerConfigurationProperties.getConsumer().get(TOPIC_AG_TASK_EMPP).getConcurrency());
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
    factory.setMessageConverter(avroMessageConverter);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(this.consumerConfigurationProperties.getConsumer().get(TOPIC_AG_TASK_EMPP).getPollTimeout());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setPauseEnabled(true);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.BATCH);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setErrorHandler(dlqAGTaskErrorHandler);
```

However, with Spring Cloud Stream I cannot find how to configure this. I can only find these configuration properties:

> spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.autoCommitOffset, enableDlq

Therefore, is it (would it be) possible to register a custom error handler and also set the AckMode to BATCH in Spring Cloud Stream?

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently we don't support these options yet at Spring Cloud Stream Level. The following issues should provide equivalent options once implemented (possibly as soon as Chelsea.RC1):

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/70

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/538